# Calling Script Tags in an href

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I'm editing my blogger template. I need to call these following script using href. What I mean in href is a TEXT with link.

I'm not good in web programming, I'm no blogger template either.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showLucky(root){ var feed = root.feed; var entries = feed.entry || []; var entry = feed.entry[0]; for (var j = 0; j < entry.link.length; ++j){if (entry.link[j].rel == 'alternate'){window.location = entry.link[j].href;}}} function fetchLuck(luck){ script = document.createElement('script'); script.src = '/feeds/posts/summary?start-index='+luck+'&max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=showLucky'; script.type = 'text/javascript'; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script); } function feelingLucky(root){ var feed = root.feed; var total = parseInt(feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t,10); var luckyNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*total);luckyNumber++; a = document.createElement('a'); a.href = '#random'; a.rel = luckyNumber; a.onclick = function(){fetchLuck(this.rel);}; a.innerHTML = 'Random Post'; document.getElementById('mbb-random').appendChild(a); } </script><script src="/feeds/posts/summary?max-results=0&alt=json-in-script&callback=feelingLucky">
</script>
```

I believe putting that chunk of codes into this href would generate an error:

```
<li><a href='CALL THE SCRIPT HERE PLS :('><i class='fa fa-line-chart'/> Growth</a></li>
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: By call you mean execute the script in the same page?

Comment: ok guys. sorry. I have this RANDOM POST button from a site: http://www.mybloggerbuzz.com/2014/05/random-post-button-blogger.html I'm trying to copy its function to my MENU LINK. I don't want a button, I want one of my MENU LINK (a text) to go to a random post when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="#" onclick="showLucky();">Growth</a>
```

This will call your javascript function instead of executing the url.

Comment: ok, upvoted. Thanks. Yea I remember this method. However, when posting the script in BLOGGER TEMPLATE, the error is like this: Error parsing XML, line 661, column 127: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup

Any idea?

Comment: I'm not familiar with BLOGGER TEMPLATE, that sounds like a specific technology; I'm not really able to tell what's happening there from what's in the original question, sorry.  From the error, it sounds like the blogger technology renders as technology and the file doesn't like something you added, it could be in this code or elsewhere.

Comment: @GlennVon the error appears when you are adding the script into "the template" ?? Try to parse the script tags in XML format. Like this one  `&lt;script&gt;`

Comment: Ok thanks Brian and yaqoob. I just had to "PARSE" the code and paste it on blogger template. Thanks.